# Target parent element within a child element's onclick event hander

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to target the ID of a parent div with an event handler in javascript?

Given the following code, when you click the image an alert fires containing the ID of the image "two".  Is it possible to return "one", which is the ID of the parent div, appear in this box instead?

```html
<div id="one">
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48" alt="" id="two" onclick="random(id)" />
</div>
    
<script>
    function random(id) {
        alert("working" + " " + id);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do `this.parentNode` to get a reference to the parent node.  Then you can get its ID with `.id`.  So `alert(this.parentNode.id)` should work.

```html
<div id="one">
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48" alt="" id="two" onclick="random(this)" />
</div>
    
<script>
    function random(node) {
        alert("working" + " " + node.parentNode.id);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have been searching high and low and finally this works! Thank you sooo much for this parentNode really solved the issue!!